# Why does the following code return the second friday in November but first friday in December?

Tags: php, date

sorry if this is a duplicate. Why does the following code error so? It returns Dec 6th currently, the first Friday in December (asking on 8 Oct 2013)

```
$thisMonth = date('m');
$year = date("Y");
$thismonthName = date("M.", mktime(0, 0, 0, $thisMonth,0,$year));
if ($thisMonth < 12) {
$nextmonthName = date("M.", mktime(0, 0, 0, $nextMonth,1,$year));
} else {
$nextMonth = 1;
$nextmonthName = date("M.", mktime(0, 0, 0, $nextMonth,1,$nextYear));
}
$thisDate = date('M j', strtotime($nextmonthName . $year . "first friday"));
print ("second friday next month is " . $thisDate);
```

but modifying it to be only next month, like so,

```
$thisMonth = date('m');
$year = date("Y");
$thismonthName = date("M.", mktime(0, 0, 0, $thisMonth,0,$year));
if ($thisMonth < 12) {
$nextmonthName = date("M.", mktime(0, 0, 0, $nextMonth,0,$year));
} else {
$nextMonth = 1;
$nextmonthName = date("M.", mktime(0, 0, 0, $nextMonth,0,$nextYear));
}
$thisDate = date('M j', strtotime($nextmonthName . $year . "first friday"));
print ("second friday next month is " . $thisDate);
```

returns Nov 8th, the second Friday in November. Why is that?

Comment: You're lacking a space in your `first friday` string, so you're actually making `Mmm 2013first friday`, plus `$nextmonth` never seems to get defined anywhere.

Comment: whoops. redefined $nextmonth and fixed the space, still not returning correctly for november. It seems to be due to the fact that November starts on a Friday

Comment: `echo date_create('second Friday of next month')->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You REALLY should investigate `DateTime`, `DateInterval`, `DatePeriod` classes.  They make this sort of thing trivial.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('second friday of next month');
$date->add($interval);
echo 'Second Friday next month is ' . $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or to get 2nd Friday for next 3 months:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$recurrence_count = 3;
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('second friday of next month');
$period = new DatePeriod($date, $interval, $recurrence_count);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: @Sven Yes `strtotime()` has the same natural language parsing capabilities, however it's output is a UNIX timestamp value, which is not nearly as flexible to work with as DateTime, DateInterval, DatePeriod. It basically gives you a one-time value instead of an interval object which could be used interchangeably with any number of DateTime or DatePeriod objects.

Comment: Hosting site wasn't using php 5.3, but I found a workaround using the above. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is way too complicated.

```
$secondNextFriday = new DateTime('first friday of +2 months'); // First friday in december
```